# Assign terms to new capability for all taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I would like to move the ability to `assign_terms` away from `edit_posts` and allocate it to a `generic_capability` so that whenever new custom taxonomies are created, anyone can assign terms, but do not necessarily have access to create new posts via `edit_posts`. Is there a way to do this?